# How to start OpenVPN conditionally?

Tags: openvpn, systemd, startup-scripts

I need to bring up an OpenVPN connection on the condition that a site is not reachable (on numerous devices spread over several heterogeneous networks). I did not find any such feature in OpenVPN directly so I ended up with a few possibilities:

- within `/etc/rc.local`: make a connectivity check and `systemctl start openvpn`

  - problem: `/etc/rc.local` is a systemv feature, not systemd (where it is optional and therefore there are probably better ways)
- create a `/etc/systemd/system/checkconnect.service` which would `Exec` a script with the same actions as above

  - `systemd` provides a [set of conditions](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#ConditionArchitecture=) on the start of a service but there is nothing related to networking.

**Is there a standard way to conditionally start OpenVPN?**

Comment: Maybe your monitoring software should fire such an action?

Comment: You could use a shell script that pings the host and if it's down, start the service, and vice versa. Then cron it to run every minute.

Comment: @neutrinus: the machines are not reachable until they bring up the VPN (except if they do not need to, of course).